# Decode within a Case statement in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Why does this query not make sense? It gives the error "missing expression."

```
update wr_rpt_group a
set a.rpt_category_id = 
case
  when (select c.control_plan from grpmisc c where 
    c.grp = a.grp and c.sect = a.sect or a.sect in ('ALL','*'))
    then decode(c.control_plan, '01', '201', '02', '202', '03', '203', '93')
      else '93'
  end      
where a.rpt_category_id = '93';
```

Thanks!

Comment: Because `c.control_plan` doesn't exist outside the case condition.. The logic in this statement seems a bit weird, can you describe what you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to change the rpt_category_id for each record whose control plan is '01' to '201', '02' to '202', etc. But I want to make sure that the record that is being updated in the table grpmisc matches the record in wr_rpt_group. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting the error that you are is that you have a case expression with no operator.  Oracle doesn't know what to do with that query in the case statement (and neither do I): are you trying to test for existence? are you looking for a specific value?

Also, it's silly and confusing (not to mention unnecessary, in this case) to use both `case` and `decode` in the same statement. I think what you wanted was this:

```
UPDATE wr_rpt_group a
SET    a.rpt_category_id   =
          CASE (SELECT c.control_plan
                FROM   grpmisc c
                WHERE  c.grp = a.grp 
                  AND  c.sect = a.sect 
                   OR  a.sect IN ('ALL', '*'))
             WHEN '01' THEN '201'
             WHEN '02' THEN '202'
             WHEN '03' THEN '203'
             ELSE '93'
          END
WHERE  a.rpt_category_id = '93';
```

Finally, I'd be awfully careful about mixing `and` and `or` without throwing in some more parenthesis. Right now, I think your query will be evaluated as `c.grp_ = a.grp and (c.sect = a.sect or a.sect in ('ALL','*'))`, but I'm just not sure.  It's always better to add some parenthesis rather than rely on your memory of the order of precedents.

Answer (score 1):

There is missing value for the expression (your query) and also `C` is used outside its scope.

See inline comments in your query as follows:

```
UPDATE WR_RPT_GROUP A
set A.RPT_CATEGORY_ID = CASE
    WHEN ( -- scope of C starts from here
        SELECT
            C.CONTROL_PLAN
        FROM
            GRPMISC C
        WHERE
            C.GRP = A.GRP
            AND C.SECT = A.SECT
                OR A.SECT IN (
                'ALL',
                '*'
            )
    ) -- scope of C ends here
    -- you have just one side expression of the operator where is other side of operation? (query) = (something)
    THEN DECODE(C.CONTROL_PLAN, '01', '201', '02', '202', '03', '203', '93')
      else '93' END WHERE A.RPT_CATEGORY_ID = '93';
```

I think you can do the following:

```
UPDATE WR_RPT_GROUP A
SET
    A.RPT_CATEGORY_ID = CASE (
        SELECT MAX(C.CONTROL_PLAN) --max is used to avoid multiple records and eventually to avoid an error
          FROM GRPMISC C
         WHERE C.GRP = A.GRP
           AND (C.SECT = A.SECT
            OR A.SECT IN ('ALL', '*')) -- combined OR conditions together using paranthesis
    )
        WHEN '01'   THEN '201'
        WHEN '02'   THEN '202'
        WHEN '03'   THEN '203'
        ELSE A.RPT_CATEGORY_ID END
WHERE A.RPT_CATEGORY_ID = '93';
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

One problem here is that you may have multiple values coming back from your select statement. If that's the case, then your update statement won't work, since you can't update a single column to multiple values. If you know that is not the case, then this should work:

```
update wr_rpt_group a
set a.rpt_category_id = select decode(c.control_plan, 
                                      '01', '201', 
                                      '02', '202', 
                                      '03', '203', 
                                      '93') 
                        from grpmisc c 
                        where c.grp = a.grp 
                        and c.sect = a.sect 
                        or a.sect in ('ALL','*'))
where a.rpt_category_id = '93'
and   exists (select 1
          from grpmisc c 
          where c.grp = a.grp 
          and c.sect = a.sect 
          or a.sect in ('ALL','*'))
```

You need the second part to ensure that a record exists to set your rpt_category_id to before you try to run the update against it. If you wanted to also ensure there are no duplicate records you can change the last part to:

```
and   1 in (select count(1)
          from grpmisc c 
          where c.grp = a.grp 
          and c.sect = a.sect 
          or a.sect in ('ALL','*'))
```

Answer (score 0):

About bracketing: AND have a higher precedence than OR, thus
the given query evaluates to

```
(c.grp_ = a.grp and c.sect = a.sect)
or
a.sect in ('ALL','*')
```

which is - in my opinion - not the intended. 
At least, bracketing as

```
c.grp_ = a.grp
and
( c.sect = a.sect or a.sect in ('ALL','*'))
```

makes more sense for me.

Or even better:

```
c.grp_ = a.grp
and
a.sect in ('ALL','*',c.sect)
```